# Can the time stamp of a Retweet be accessed?

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to use the Twitter API: `GET statuses/retweets/:id`
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweets-id

It doesn't seem like the API returns the time a Tweet was retweeted. It only shows when it was created. Is this true? And if so, is there any other way of being able to retrieve the retweet timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Introduction to Tweet JSON](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json):

> If you are working with a Retweet object, then that object will contain two Tweet objects, complete with two User objects.  The Tweet that was Retweeted is referred to as the 'original' Tweet and is displayed under the 'retweeted_status' key. If a Retweet gets Retweeted, the 'retweet_status' will still point to the original Tweet, meaning the intermediate Retweet is not included.

The top-level `created_at` attribute should be the time of the retweet that you're looking for. The original tweet is embedded inside the retweet object as the `retweeted_status` and it has its own (earlier) timestamp.